# Modify matplotlib generated histogram before plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I use matplotlib `hist2d` to bin a large dataset of points and plot it in polar projection.

However, I'd like now to modify the data after it has been binned, namely to normalize along one of the directions. That is, for any abscissa, the sum of the histogram values along ordinates is 1.

Matplotlib gives the binned data among the returns of `hist2d`, which I can modify as desired. However, when calling `plt.show()` after this, it is the originally calculated data, and not the modified data, which is plotted.

Is it possible to update the data to be plotted in the given axis?

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

max_d=100
bins=5

from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng()
angles = rng.uniform(0,np.pi,1000)
distances = rng.exponential(max_d/2,1000)
distance_normalize,edges=np.histogram(distances,2*bins,range=[0,max_d])
distance_normalize=1./distance_normalize

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax1.set_xticks(np.pi*np.linspace(0,1,7))
bins=10
ax1.set_yticks(10*np.arange(bins+1))

#call to matplotlib
hist_data,xedges,yedges,image=ax1.hist2d(angles,distances,bins=(18,bins),range=[[0,np.pi],[0,max_d]])

#modification of calculated histogram
hist_data=np.einsum('ij,j->ij',hist_data,distance_normalize)

#diplaying shows unmodified data
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Call https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html rather than `hist2d` and then use `pcolormesh` or `imshow` to display the 2-d histogram once you have the data the way you want it.  Thats all Matplotlib does.

Comment: Hi @JodyKlymak and thanks for comment, I should have stressed that I'm using polar projection (see MWE), it seems `imshow` doesn't work in this case but `pcolormesh` does.